# Averaging of a differential form.

Tags: differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\omega$ be a differential form on $S^1.$ There is an action of a circle on itself by rotations ($A: S^1 \to S^1$ as $A(x)=A+x$ if we think of a circle as an additive group). Let's define the differential form $A(\omega)$ which is the "averaging" (namely, $A(\omega)$ is invariant with respect to the action $S^1$) of the form $\omega$ as $A(\omega_p)(x)= \int_{S^1} A^{*} \omega_p (x) dA.$

**My question is**: how to realize that $A(\omega)$ and $\omega$ are cohomologous. I think that's because of connectedness of a circle but I can't find such $f$ that $df=\omega-A(\omega).$

Comment: A $1$-form $\phi$ is cohomologous to zero on $S^1$ iff $\int_{S^1}\phi=0$. This must be the case if $\phi=\omega-A(\omega)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I want to do it without this statement (I want to prove this statement from my question).

Comment: This is actually false, as it stands, because you haven't normalized $dA$ to have $\int_{S^1} dA = 1$. But, once you have, set $\phi=\omega-A(\omega)$ and define $f(x) = \int_0^x \phi$. Check that (a) it's well defined and (b) $df =\phi$.